# How to perform unique validation on six dropdown fields in my Google form

Tags: forms, validation, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google form. There are six dropdowns. Each dropdown offers the same list of items (cities). I need to ensure the user selects a unique city from each dropdown. (It is mandatory to select at least one city. The rest are optional.)

The form is set up to allow users to resubmit (edit) their response. So whether they are submitting a response for the first time, or editing a response, I need to apply this validation.

I tried everything with the help of chatGPT but the form would always allow the user to submit their response even if it contained duplicate answers to the dropdowns.

Comment: I don't think that there is any way to do it before submission.  I would use html form instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Cooper. This was my sinking suspicion. Unfortunately using an HTML form is out of the question. :(